# Given $A$ is $6×6 $ real symetric matrix of rank $5$ , then to determine rank of $A^{2}+ A+I $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A$ is $6×6 $matrix of rank $5$ , then to determine rank of $A^{2}+ A+I $.

I knowthat rank of matrix doesnot change when we square it , but how to proceed in this question.Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: It is not true that the rank of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A^2$ in general. Take a non-zero matrix $A$ with $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here two examples which might give you the answer:

I know it is somewhat pathological. Let $diag(v)$ denote a zero matrix that has the entries of $v$ on it's diagonal.

Let $A = diag(e^{2\pi i / 3}\cdot[1,1,1,1,1,0])$ then $A \in \mathbb C^{6 \times 6}$ and obviously $A^2+A+I = diag([0,0,0,0,0,1])$ has rank 1.

On the other hand if $A = diag([1,1,1,1,1,0])$ then the rank of $A^2+A+I$ is 6.

EDIT: This should suggest that you cannot say what rank this matrix will have, since I've constructed two examples, one with rank 1 and one with rank 6, and the similarly you can create examples of any rank in between.

Comment: So answer is 5 ?

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks, that is what i intended to write!

Comment: @godonichia I showed you two examples that satisfied your conditiosn, one with rank 1 and one with rank 5, so what do you think will be the answer?

Comment: @flawr shouldn't rank in your second example be 5

Comment: @godonichia No, since in the second example $A^2+A+I = diag([3,3,3,3,3,1])$

Comment: i havenot actually understood notation in first example , is e^(2pi/3) multiplied by 111110 or what?

Comment: Yes, just normal scalar vector multiplication. It is $e^{2\pi i /3}$ btw.

Comment: What is reason for choosing 2pi/3 .also if matrix is real thenrank would be 6 right ?

Comment: Please do not forget the $i$, $\omega = e^{2\pi i /3}$!!! This is a third unit root, so $\omega^2+\omega+1 = 0$. The matrix is complex and cannot be real, and as you do only have one real third root. But of course you can still construct examples in the real numbers.

Comment: if i have a symetric matrix, then what will rank be

Comment: I have liitle doubt in trig here , we have three roots of unity as 1, $e^{ipi\3}$ , $e^{i2pi\3} $ .which one are you taking

Comment: You need a complex one, since you want $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. If you use the real one you get $\omega^2+\omega+1=3$,but we want it to be $0$ in order to get the lowest possible rank.

Answer (score 7):

Given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$ is an eigenvalue for $B=A^2+A+I$ (same eigenvector).

So, if neither $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$ or $\overline{\omega}=\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$ belong to the spectrum of $A$, the rank of $B$ is six.